# React: `'` can be escaped with `&apos;`

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I got this error, but only on VErsel not in localstore. Why the difference?

```
./src/pages/acl/index.tsx
20:58:47.129    25:80  Error: `'` can be escaped with `&apos;`, `&lsquo;`, `&#39;`, `&rsquo;`.  react/no-unescaped-entities
```

Shall I scan through all the code for special characters? Why client `yarn build` does not raise error locally?

```js
  return (
    <Grid container spacing={6}>
      <Grid item md={6} xs={12}>
        <Card>
          <CardHeader title='Common' />
          <CardContent>
            <Typography sx={{ mb: 4 }}>No ability is required to view this card</Typography>
            <Typography sx={{ color: 'primary.main' }}>This card is visible to 'user' and 'admin' both</Typography>
          </CardContent>
        </Card>
      </Grid>
      {ability?.can('read', 'analytics') ? (
        <Grid item md={6} xs={12}>
          <Card>
            <CardHeader title='Analytics' />
            <CardContent>
              <Typography sx={{ mb: 4 }}>User with 'Analytics' subject's 'Read' ability can view this card</Typography>
              <Typography sx={{ color: 'error.main' }}>This card is visible to 'admin' only</Typography>
            </CardContent>
          </Card>
        </Grid>
      ) : null}
    </Grid>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're getting an ESLint error.

You can either:

1. Disable ESLint in your `next.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
  eslint: {
    // Warning: This allows production builds to successfully complete even if
    // your project has ESLint errors.
    ignoreDuringBuilds: true,
  },
}
```

2. Disable rule in `.eslintrc.*`:

```
"rules": {
  "react/no-unescaped-entities": "off"
}
```

3. Disable in specific file with comment at top of the file

```
1. /* eslint react/no-unescaped-entities */
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution to avoiding this warning using backticks `{`'your quoted word'`}`

```js
<Typography sx={{ color: 'primary.main' }}>This card is visible to {`'user'`} and {`'admin'`} both</Typography>
```

Your output will look like this "This card is visible to 'user' and 'admin' both"